# Bootstrap Modal Popup showing black screen in Shopify theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, shopify

Here is my html code:

```
      <!doctype html>
      <html> 
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      </head>

      <body >

        <div class="container">
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>
        <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          Open modal
        </button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal" id="myModal" >
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

              <!-- Modal Header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>

              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body..
              </div>

              <!-- Modal footer -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </body>

        </html>
```

I have included the same code in my Shopify `theme.liquid` file.

When I use the code in a standalone HTML file, it works fine.

But, when I include it in Shopify `theme.liquid` file, it shows a translucent black empty screen without popup modal when Open Modal Button is clicked.

Here is my Shopify URL - https://laaoo.myshopify.com

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

To your Angularjs Controller, add the following code:

```
$scope.removeGreyScreen = function () { $(".modal-backdrop").remove(); };
```

and on your close button, call the above function as follows

```
ng-click="removeGreyScreen()"
```

basically,

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="removeGreyScreen()">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not using Angular

Comment: use this code " $(".modal-backdrop").remove(); " and call it from button click event from JQuery or javascript.